# Mysql тормозит с объемом в 300MB

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер. Объем таблицы где-то 350 000 записей (300MB). В пма так же очень тормозит

К примеру

```
select * from table limit 10
```

> 0.0009sec

```
select * from table order by id desc limit 10
```

БД упала или грузит минуты 3-5. Сам сервер не слабый, да и объем вроде как не большой. С чем связано может быть? как решить это? Структура таблицы простая. Оптимизацию сделать не удается, падает.

Comment: Дос атака

Comment: А вы проверьте нагрузку на сервер? Что скажет? Мб и в правду что то не то?